# How to assign the row names of a dataframe as the column names of another dataframe?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes:

`meth_df`

```
> dput(meth_df[0:5,0:5])
structure(list(`TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A` = c(0.611033076810465, 0.786837244239289, 
0.531054614303851, 0.711916183761331, 0.758443223998425), `TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A` = c(0.468013052647261, 
0.386177267500376, 0.508623627469028, 0.403601275088479, 0.754642399207848
), `TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A` = c(0.593559707995411, 0.54983504208745, 
0.535207192925841, 0.613971903755576, 0.717278085189431), `TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A` = c(0.638211007873003, 
0.319561448644096, 0.526699541432941, 0.450002172806716, 0.736440001203422
), `TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A` = c(0.603998109440889, 0.638039512259872, 
0.584328151056768, 0.594021097192165, 0.818583455926719)), row.names = c("A1BG", 
"A1CF", "A2BP1", "A2LD1", "A2M"), class = "data.frame")
```

`class_df`

```
> dput(class_df[0:5,])
structure(list(X = c("TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A", "TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A", 
"TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A", "TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A", "TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A"), 
    survival = c("lts", "lts", "lts", "lts", "lts"), type = c("tumor", 
    "tumor", "tumor", "tumor", "tumor"), subtype = c("kirp", 
    "kirp", "kirp", "kirp", "kirp")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

The columns of `meth_df` corresponds with the `X` column of `class_df`. The actual `meth_df` has 19143 obs. of 865 variables. The actual `class_df` has 1146 obs. of 4 variables.

First, I append the survival info to corresponding `X` columns in `class_df`

```
cols <- c("X", "survival")
rownames(class_df) <- apply(class_df[,cols], 1, paste, collapse="_")
```

Now, I want to assign the row names of `class_df` as the column names of `meth_df` if the existing column names of `meth_df` matches the `X` column of `class_df`. I'm not sure how to do it.

Desired output:

```
> dput(meth_df[0:5,0:5])
structure(list(`TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A_lts` = c(0.611033076810465, 0.786837244239289, 
0.531054614303851, 0.711916183761331, 0.758443223998425), `TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A_lts` = c(0.468013052647261, 
0.386177267500376, 0.508623627469028, 0.403601275088479, 0.754642399207848
), `TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A_lts` = c(0.593559707995411, 0.54983504208745, 
0.535207192925841, 0.613971903755576, 0.717278085189431), `TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A_lts` = c(0.638211007873003, 
0.319561448644096, 0.526699541432941, 0.450002172806716, 0.736440001203422
), `TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A_lts` = c(0.603998109440889, 0.638039512259872, 
0.584328151056768, 0.594021097192165, 0.818583455926719)), row.names = c("A1BG", 
"A1CF", "A2BP1", "A2LD1", "A2M"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Just a quick note that R indexes start at 1, so all of your `0:5`s look a little weird, you should probably use `1:5`.

Comment: With your sample data, it's as simple as `names(meth_df) = row.names(class_df)`, because the matches are all there, once each, in the correct order. It would help if you could edit your example to include some of what makes the real problem harder than that: you say 865 `meth_df` columns and 1146 `class_df` rows, so clearly it's more complicated. Are there duplicates to worry about? If there is no match, then the column name stays the same? Just switching one order and introducing one no-match to the sample would help make sure an answer really works, not just for this ultra-simple case.